# How do I close a window after the user clicks on the close button in file upload?

Tags: javascript

We have a requirement to close the popup window itself when the user clicks on the cancel button in the file upload.

1. main.html
2. popup.html

`popup.html` contains `<input type="file"`.

Now we have a requirement that when a user clicks on the cancel button in the file upload window `popup.html` should also be closed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script language="javascript"> 
    function openModalDlg() { 
        window.open( "test.html", "", 'width=400,height=100'); 
    } 
    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <p> 
        Click 
        <a href="#" onclick="openModalDlg();">here</a> 
        to open modal dialog 
    </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Main.html                                                                <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <script language="javascript">
  function openModalDlg()
  {
   window.open( "test.html", "",
'width=400,height=100');
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
 Click <a href="#" onclick="openModalDlg();">here</a> to open modal dialog
 </p>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close) method:

```
<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="window.close();" />
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function check(){
     document.getElementById("ch").value="1";

    }

        window.onload = init;

        function init() {

        window.onfocus = whenInFocus;
        window.onblur = function() {window.onfocus = whenInFocus;};};

Comment: function whenInFocus() {

         alert(document.getElementById("ch").value);
         if(document.getElementById("ch").value=="1") {
          window.close();
         }
         window.onfocus = null;

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body >

    <input type="file" name="upfile" onclick="check()" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ch" value="0" />

</body>

</html>